# ScenarioScoped mixes up token with SureFire parallel execution (Java + Maven)

Tags: java, maven, parallel-processing, cucumber, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm using Cucumber for my API tests and save the shared context in ScenarioContext class which is marked with @ScenarioScoped and @Injected per Steps class. Of course some features use steps from cross-classes as well (which causes the bug described below, but I dont want to change that due to DRY).

TestS run fine when I do them sequentially however they mix up the token Im saving in scenarioContext when I run them parallelly.

Has anyone faced this issue before? I tried with separate runners and 1 runner however the result was the same. Here's my pom.xml corresponding config:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Suite.java</include>
                </includes>
                <forkCount>8C</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Above configuration should give the highest level of separation but my tests still fail at random (which does NOT happen with sequential run).

I've read following documentations and didnt find corresponding answers:
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/process-communication.html
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

---

@Alexey R. - Im adding additional code :)

So my ScenarioContext class looks as follows:

```
@ScenarioScoped
public class ScenarioContext extends Base {
    Map<String, Object> scenarioContext;

    public ScenarioContext() throws Exception {
        this.scenarioContext = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void setContext(Context key, Object value) {
        scenarioContext.put(key.toString(), value);
    }

    public Object getContext(Context key) {
        return scenarioContext.get(key.toString());
    }
-   some other general shortcut methods
}
```

And in my Steps classes aforementioned scenarioContext is called as follows:

```
public class myStepsClass extends Base {
    @Inject
    private ScenarioContext scenarioContext;

    public myStepsClass(ScenarioContext scenarioContext) throws Exception {
        this.scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
    }
```

+[gherkin steps getting/setting values to scenarioContext]

I have also added a System.out.println("New scenario Context") in Scenario Context constructor and it seems to be printed out once per thread however I still get different results when tests are run in parallel :(

Comment: `ScenarioScoped` means that the object is recreated for each scenario so no matter if they are running in parallel or not. Can you show some representative code so that we could reproduce it on our own.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I have updated my query as the comment section didnt allow for such long answer :)

Comment: What I can see straight away is that you are using injection wrong. You should either use inject annotation for field or use annotation for constructor. If you inject on a per-field level do not re-assign the same field with constructor. Second - do your tests use any other shared things except of that context? Or probably static references? What unit framework do you use? JUnit4/5? Or TestNg? All that is important because I just checked and it seems that `fork` mode does not work with cucumber-junit4

Comment: I am using junit 4.13.2
It doesnt? I have added the info to my error messages and it seems to work:
Started in thread: 1, in JVM: 30264@COMP
Started in thread: 1, in JVM: 2304@COMP

I have tried to not add the variable in the constructor but there's compilation error "Variable scenarioContext might not have been initialized"

I have also done it as solution 1 - so @Incject in front of constructor but it didnt do the trick :( I am not using any static references.

private final Scenario Context scenarioContext;
@ Inject
public myStepsClass(ScenarioContext[...])

Comment: The only shared context is this ScenarioContext, they use some common classes to just "do the work" behind the steps as per cucumber guidelines. However there are no more contexts

Comment: Do you have your code somewhere? I believe the issue is hidden somewhere out of the shown example.

Comment: No, its not openly shared and I believe I cannot share the whole repo :(

Comment: alright. when you `still get different results` what it actually means? Did you try to debug? Why are results different? Why are you sure it is the issue of injection.

Comment: It means when I run my tests in sequence I have exactly same amount of failed tests each time. However when running them in parallel I get different (higher) number of errors.

I am not sure but it looks so in 90% - the error I get is 403 when I call endpoint getting my access token. I get the same error e.g. in Postman when I try to get my final access token for second time with previoysly obtained tokens from 2fa process. Hence my assumption is - something has used my combination of 2fa tokens and depending on 'whats first' in parallel run I get random throw of 403 errors

Comment: I would start from logging tokens your threads are trying to use. This is how you will either confirm or deny your theory.

Comment: It may also be possible that requesting a new token invalidates the old ones. I would start by simplifying the problem reproducer to one passing scenario copied a few times. Then add logging about the thread, token generated and token used.

Comment: Okay Ill try both solutuions then, thank you for the help outs :)